# Changed my domain from www to non-www, and now my cookies are no longer being created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies

I have a Rails 6 application that uses cookies to store a `remember me` token. The domain forced the `www.` for the last few months, but I decided to get rid of it and make non-`www.` the default.

The `remember me` token now no longer works. When logging in the user is redirected to the root as if they were logged in, but they aren't. The `remember me` cookie is never created. There is no error in the logs at all. It's as if everything happened as it should. 
Straight up setting a cookie, without any prior action, also does not work.

The token is created using: `cookies.encrypted.permanent[:remember_token] = token`.

It works perfectly fine in development, and worked perfectly fine on the `www.` domain before.

I've tried to set the cookie domain in my `application.rb` like so: `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: "_app_name", domain: :all`, to absolutely no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Back in the day, the rule was that if you changed your session cookie domain, you should also change the name of the cookie to make sure there's no accidental overlap (as explaind here: https://sam-low.com/ruby/rails/cookie/changing-rails-session-cookie-domain.html).

I'm not 100% sure if this is still the case but it's relatively low effort and IMO definitely worth a try.